# How to replace annotation @Dependent and @ApplicationScoped in java SE and jersey?

Tags: java, annotations, jersey, javabeans, java-ee-6

I use java 8 SE and jersey. I found example of jwt service [here](https://github.com/cassiomolin/jersey-jwt/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cassiomolin/example/security/service/UsernamePasswordValidator.java),
there is used java 6 EE.
Does someone know about analogs of this annotations or other solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by replacing this annotations on @Singelton and adding

**ApplicationBinder**

```
public class ApplicationBinder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(UserService.class).to(UserService.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

**ResourceConfig**

```
public class ApplicationConfig  extends ResourceConfig {
    public ApplicationConfig() {
        register(new ApplicationBinder());
        packages(true, "api");
    }
}
```

than I just can inject bean-classes by annotation @Inject